# Specific Problem with escaping quotes in XML/Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tibco

I have specific problem with some inbound messages that contains quotes(for example) **'s-Hertogenbosch**  and i need to escape the first single quote because i can't inject whole node-set in the DataBase..can anyone tell me solution how can i ignore that quote?..or briefly how at all can i dynamically escape unnecessary quotes in every inbound message except first and last one.

I tryed with translate($InboundMessage, '  "  ', "(blankspace)" ) and it worked fine but it removed all quotes..i need to keep first and last one..for example my Inbound message is

'Last year i visited 's-Hertogenbosch '..that single quote makes harm because on the output i got 'Last year i visited' without the name of the city.

Solution?

Regards.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Yes,actualy we are using that in Tibco BW

Comment: You are building the XPath expression in an external tool, right? I'm guessing "TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks"? If that's so, does this software offer non-xpath string split and -join functions you can employ to build your expression?

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression....

```
 <xsl:value-of select='replace($InboundMessage, "(.)&apos;+(.)", "$1$2")'/>
```

Or, if you want to do it for double quotes...

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($InboundMessage, '(.)&quot;+(.)', '$1$2')"/>
```

EDIT: If you can only use XSLT1.0 and XPATH 1.0, then you have to do some string manipluation

```
<xsl:value-of select='concat(substring($InboundMessage, 1, 1), translate(substring($InboundMessage, 2, string-length($InboundMessage) - 2), "&apos;", ""), substring($InboundMessage, string-length($InboundMessage)))'/>
```

Alternatively, given your comment about building SQL, you could just replace all apostrophes, and put the outer apostrophes back in the SQL string you build

```
<xsl:value-of select='concat("INSERT INTO ", $Destination, " (", $Column, ") VALUES (&apos;", translate($InboundMessage, "&apos;", ""), "&apos;)")'/>
```

Comment: Still is not working..Unfortunately replace() function don't exist in Tibco BW XSLT

Comment: I can inject this node if i use JDBC Update activity when i wrote SQL manualy with question mark and parameters for example 'INSERT INTO Destination (Column) VALUES (?)' and then in the Input just drag and drop the message...but i need to to this dynamic with SQL Direct when i need to wrote all the SQL in one sentence with variables and concatination..for example concat( 'INSERT INTO $Destination ($Column) VALUES ($InboundMessage)')....    Look out..in the first example i use regular Values,and in the second example i use Variables..because of that one single quote i can't inject value in DB

Comment: I have edited my answer to show an XSLT 1.0 solution